# What species other than humans and E.T.s managed to survive from the galaxy far far away until E.T. the Extraterrestrial was released?

Tags: star-wars, character-identification, et-the-extra-terrestrial

What species other than humans and E.T.s managed to survive from the galaxy far far away and a long time ago until E.T. the Extraterrestrial phoned home?

Comment: On reflection, I think this question is based on a false premise (one that's addressed in its entirety in the dupe).